# voice chat over internet implementation iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk, chat, voice

Can any one tell me how can i implement voice chat in iphone sdk . 
Game is used for voice chat over bluetooth ..
i want my app to have voice chat option over the internet

Thanks
Yasir

Answer (score 2):

Apple's GameKit framework provides evertyhing you need to implement in-game chat.

The full documentation is here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/AddingVoiceChattoaMatch/AddingVoiceChattoaMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH11-SW11

Assuming you have allready connected the App to one or more other players using GameKit, you can start the voice chat like so:

```
-(void) startInGameChat {
//Set up audio session
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:myErr];
[audioSession setActive: YES error: myErr];

GKMatch* match;
GKVoiceChat *teamChannel = [[match voiceChatWithName:@"redTeam"] retain];
GKVoiceChat *allChannel = [[match voiceChatWithName:@"allPlayers"] retain];

//Start the chat
[teamChannel start];

//Enable Mic
teamChannel.active = YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One best way to do it using XMPP Framework. Using XMPP you can send files & text to other persons. Using it you can record voice message & send it across. I did lot of R & D n that to implement the jabber sever on ios  with XMPP protocal.

for  more info just move to link: to implement jabber with XMPP protocal.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/

You can also see this link  for simple chating  in ios :
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/